# How can I use a predicted machine algorithm model to find specific inputs?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, prediction

I am relatively new to machine learning and now I am working on my thesis regarding that!
My goal is to find a prediction model to see if the strain of the three zones is similar to each other or not.

For this purpose, three different zones for stress, the dimension of a cell including x, y, z, the structure type of the part, and the structure's thickness are considered as inputs.
Outputs are three strains corresponding with each stress, which I want to put the target as "Are these three strains similar to each other or not?". So, it could be considered a classification problem.

Here is my issue:

In the next step, when I get a well-predicted model, I want to define three stresses and then the achieved model gives me a best combination of other inputs regarding the most similar strains for three zones.

In fact, I want to get some specific inputs by giving other inputs and outputs. Should I use optimization methods using the achieved ML model? Or, is there any else solution for that?

I appreciate it if you could help me guys!